# how to fix this error in npx create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, create-react-app

Till yesterday everything was working fine and then suddenly today this error is showing up. I dont know what configuration or something I changed or got changed by mistake but now this error is always showing up.[image]

Comment: Have you tried running `npm i @typescript-eslint/parser` in an exisiting project to verify if this is a global issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello there was a general problem with npm and yarn servers [npm status](https://status.npmjs.org/) it looks like it resolved maybe try again?

Comment: Yeah it is now working maybe servers had problems for few hours